# Why are these ASP variables not displaying right?

Tags: asp.net

```
<% 
Dim myNext
Dim myPrev
myNext = cat.QSPage+1
myPrev = cat.QSPage-1
%>
<% if cat.QSPage=1 then %>
    <link rel='next' href="/example_<%=myNext%>.htm" />
<% else %>
    <link rel='prev' href="/example_<%=myPrev%>.htm" />
    <link rel='next' href="/example_<%=myNext%>.htm" />
<% end if %>
```

The above changes the ASP <%= into &lt;%= and I have tried every variation I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
<link rel='next' href="/logo-design-example_<%=myNext%>.htm" />
```

Try this

```
<link rel='next' href="<%= '/logo-design-example_' & myNext & '.htm' %>" />
```

If the above doesnot work then try the following

```
sub getUrl()
  response.write('/logo-design-example_' & myNext & '.htm')
end sub

<link rel='next' href="<% call getUrl()%>" />
```

I forgot most of the ASP but i think it should work.

EDIT::
try this now. It is working on my end. Let me know if you find anyother issue.

```
<link rel='next' href="<%= "/logo-design-example_" & myNext & ".htm" %>" />
```

Comment: what happens ? It gets converted like this --> <%= into &lt;%=   ?? Just to be sure you are using Classic ASP.right ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check it now. It is working on my end.

Comment: Yes, that one worked, however i was sure I tried that already, but as long as it works, I am good, thanks :)